# On a custom template, should I use wp_footer?

Tags: php

I have started to learn about WP. I was asking myself the other day : should I use, in my custom template, the wp_footer() to call my scripts or should I go with static script?
I can't seem to understand how wp_footer works, tho I know it is a do_action but I actually don't want to change the "core" for wp_footer, I just want to add my own scripts in the footer.

Should I go to the function that call wp_head and add my scripts there or should I write it down in a static footer.php like

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php function theme_footerscript(){
wp_enqueue_script('main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_footerscript');  ?>
```

this way you will add a script on footer (add this code in functions.php).
if you set the last parameter to true, then the script will be at the bottom of html page. 
you can check on [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)